# Parameter coming blank to asmx web service from objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asmx

I am calling an .Net asmx web service from my xcode debugger. In the debugger I can see that I am passing some value but on the .net web service it is coming as blank.

On the web service end I am writing to a log file. I see that the method is getting called but the parameter is coming blank/null. I have pasted the code below. I have also pasted the wsdl. Any reason why the parameters are coming as blank

```
-(void) fetchData: (NSString*)userid 
{
    NSString *requestSoapMsg = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="
     "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
     "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" "
     "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
     "<soap:Body>\n"
     "<UpdateRegForUser xmlns=\"http://soft.com\">\n"
     "<userid>%@</userid>\n"    
     "</UpdateRegForUser>\n"
     "</soap:Body>\n"
     "</soap:Envelope>\n", userid];

    NSLog(@"%@", requestSoapMsg); // i can see the value here

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://soft.com:8000/services/registration.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSString *requestSoapMsgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestSoapMsg length]];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://soft.com/UpdateRegForUser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:requestSoapMsgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestSoapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(!result)
        NSLog(@"FAILEDDDDDDDDD!!");
```

WSDL -

```
POST /services/registration.asmx HTTP/1.1

Host: soft.com


Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: length

SOAPAction: "http://soft.com/UpdateRegForUser"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateRegForUser xmlns="http://soft.com/">
      <userid>string</userid>
    </UpdateRegForUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Given the significance of line breaks in HTTP, I didn't remove any of the line breaks from your WSDL sample. Please edit it to remove any line breaks that you added to the question (i.e., that were not in the WSDL data your application sent to the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem.

I wrote a C# console application and invoked the web service. At the same time, I captured the trace from fiddler. The fiddler trace showed me that xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" should come before xsi. I saved the xml and made my request xml EXACTLY the same. It started working.